# Base case of the outside term of Inside-outside algorihm

Tags: computational-linguistics

I am studying the Inside-Outside algorithm, which is a branch of EM algorithm. (As resources, I am referring http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/io.pdf and https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/465/iobasics.pdf)

According the definition, given a tree structure, the Outside term  $\beta$ is the sum of probabilities for all outside trees given a node. The Inside term $\alpha(A, i, j)$ is the sum of potentials for all trees spanning
words xi . . . xj, rooted in the symbol A.

However, I cannot understand why the base case of the Outside term $\beta(S, 1, n) = 1$ and $\beta(A, 1, n) = 0 $ for all $  A ∈ N$ such that $A \neq S$. Especially, $\beta(S, 1, n) = 1$ is a biggest headache.Here, S is a root node and A is a non-terminal node.

With $\beta(S, 1, n)$, the root S cannot have any outside trees, so I do not know how to make sense of why it is 1.

Can you give me some intuition/understanding please?

Comment: On a tangential note, LaTeX doesn't seem to appear on this particular stackexchange (at least for me). Is there a setting or something to enable it?